# Unable to load Static resource (JS file) to LWC component in Salesforce

Tags: javascript, components, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I tried using the code below, but was not able to get the JavaScript file from the static resource (Feedback.js) and this file is not in ZIP folder.

```
loadCurrencyJS() {

    window.loadingCurrencyjs = true;
    let path = "/resource/Feedback";
    loadScript(this, path).then((res)=>{
        console.log("Currencyjs loaded");
        window.loadingCurrencyjs = false;
        window.CurrencyjsLoaded = true;
    }).catch(e=>{
        console.log("File not loaded");
        window.CurrencyjsLoaded = false;
    })
  }
```

I also tried with below code:

```
import Qualtrics_Feedback from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/Qualtrics_Feedback';
Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, Qualtrics_Feedback)
        ]).then(() => {
            window.console.log("Load");
        }).catch(error => {
            window.console.log("Error: "+error);
            });
```

Comment: Is it really mandatory for your JS to be a Static Resource ?

Answer (score 1):

I think here is the documentation you're looking for :

- [Import javascript code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_share_code)
- [Access static resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_resources)

For js code I would recommend to use first method unless you're trying to import a library. Please note that library doing DOM manipulation will probably not work because of [Lightning Locker](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_locker_service).